# Need old music transferred to new computer

Tags: itunes, music, data-transfer, accounts

My computer crashed and actually caught on fire destroying everything that was in it. I purchased a new computer and a new ISP and email address. But, my new computer does not have my ITunes library in it, just 1 song. I have contacted Apple about this. They sent me a link to get me started but, it really doesn't help me because of the old email address is not the current new address. Because of the different ISP's. I am stuck. I have Windows 8.1.

Comment: Hi Bill, welcome to the community. Can you please provide more info? What was your old computer running? Was it a Windows machine or a Mac? Was your hard drive destroyed as well? Do you have any backups of your old computer anywhere? Were you paying for Apple Music or iTunes Match? And, what do you mean when you say Apple's advice doesn't help because of the email address changing? Do you mean your Apple ID has changed? Or that you haven't changed it to reflect your new email address?

Answer (score 1):

Your old Apple ID is probably still valid and I imaging the old password will still work.

For example, if I have an email address blahblahblah@something.com and create an Apple ID it's just using that email address as my username. It is not actually using your email account's password to authenticate. Does that make sense? I'd just try logging in with your old Apple ID (email address) and your last known password.

If all else fails then I hope you had a [rescue email address](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201356) setup for your Apple ID!